# How deal with exponential distribution of data during principal component analysis

Tags: pca, data-transformation

I am trying to do PCA on a series of variables (all are positive, real numbers) using correlation and varimax rotation. All the computation is done in R.

Although I got high loadings for all variables of interest, the frequency distribution of the obtained PC2 shows an exponential distribution, meaning that the extremes of one side of this axis contains a very small number of observations.

I have tried several transformations: logarithmic, square root, centering and scaling, and rank, and none of them solves the problem. What do you think I should do? Leave it like that?

For further contextualization, I want to use the obtained PCs for their use in a multiple regression analysis.

Comment: Why does it matter what the distribution is?

Comment: All that PCA guarantees is a set of uncorrelated components, ordered from most to least variable. You seem to be thinking there's a promise of what? Gaussian distributions? Symmetric distributions? Note that for multiple regression neither is required as an assumption about any of the variables.

Comment: Thanks, as I previously understood, having an exponential distribution in my PCs makes less linear the relationships with any of the other variables in the regression, thus losing statistical power. the PCs have both negative and positive numbers so i cant just take squareroot transformations nor logs previously to a multiple regression. Thats why i was trying to transform the initial variables previously to the PCA procedure.

Comment: This is contradictory or at least confusing on when you are doing, or thinking about doing, the transformations: your comment here does not seem to match your question. But the time to consider transformations is usually before, not after, a PCA. I don't know what power has to do with linearity or nonlinearity unless it means that you may get a poor answer if you ask an inappropriate statistical question.

Comment: @nickcox, dunno if i got your point. I'll try to leave my question clearer:

Comment: Transform variables **before** you try PCA, not afterwards. Transformation will disturb the lack of correlation between PCs, one of their supposed virtues.

Comment: I got a principal component that has an exponential distribution and i want to use it as an independent variable in a multiple regression analysis. its that ok, or should i transform the variables? if its not ok, how should i transform so as to get a more normal frequency distribution in the obtained Princomp axis. Please remember i tried several types of transformation without achieving normality.

Comment: I just discovered that there are in fact PCA that deal with exponential distributions(http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/li10b/li10b.pdf) however, its still obscure to me how to implement that in R.